# Noob: pyautogui code

Tags: python, user-interface, automation

I am still very much at the start of learning about programming. 
I played around with python lately and wanted to do a little project about GUI automation with pyautogui. The idea is to make a very basic and simple Instagram automation program that double clicks waits a random amount of seconds (chosen so that the maximum like "per hour rate" is not exceeded) and then scrolls on and repeats infinitely. 
Here is what I got so far:

```
#instaclicker-bot
import pyautogui 
import random
while True
    pyautogui.moveTo(500,500,duration=0,25) #move cursor over image in webbrowser
    pyautogui.doubleClick(500,500) #doubleclick to "like"
    waittime = random.radInt(20,40) #wait between 20 and 40 seconds to emulate random behaviour
    print "waiting for %d seconds" % waittime #print chosen wait time
    time.sleep(waittime) #wait for chosen wait time
    pyautogui.scroll(500) #scroll to position mouse over next picture below
```

I am getting syntax errors and "Indent block detected" errors all the time. Also, is the variable usage correct?

I am well aware that bots and automation of any kind are against Instagram's terms of use. I am not intending to use this in any bad way. This is just intended to be a fun project for me.

Also this is my first post/asking for help on stack exchange I hope I didn't make any stupid mistakes, and apologize in advance if I did something wrong.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of syntax errors and compile time errors in the code.

- replace `while True` with `while True:`
- replace `pyautogui.moveTo(500,500,duration=0,25)` with
  `pyautogui.moveTo(500,500,25,duration=0)` because in python, non
  keyword arguments cannot follow keyword arguments. (refer [this](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/controlflow.html?highlight=keyword%20args#keyword-arguments))
- replace `waittime = random.radInt(20,40)` with `waittime =

  random.randint(20,40)`
- and finally `import time`.

I suggest using an IDE like [cloud9](https://c9.io) which would give a quick feedback on these errors.

Comment: Thank you very much! I fixed all those things in your list but now I am getting an import error for pyautogui right at the start although the module is installed correctly. It says:    ImportError: No module named pyautogui

Comment: @Nixxon, if  `pyautogui` module is successfully installed, you might be missing some dependencies depending on the OS you are running on esp. if you are on Mac/Linux . Info [here](https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like this.

random.radint == 2

or

```
random.randint(1, 10) == 1
```